# Background images and Images.xcassets

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, image

In my xcode 6 project (built for iphone) and in my storyboard i have a imageView thats i want to cover the whole canvas that acts as a background image. I'm really struggling to get my head around the Images.xcassets, i have added a new image set and in the attributes inspector i have set devices to device specific, in the check box i have iPhone and Retina 4-Inch checked. My question is what size should my images be at 1x, 2x, Retina 4 2x and 3x to scale the whole background. I think my image sizes are correct but the image size for Retina 4 2x is really confusing me.

Comment: what do you mean with "but the image size for Retina 4 2x is really confusing me."?

Comment: I am not sure what size i should make my Background images to cover the whole canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple gives the full resolution you need to do the images for all the devices.

I leave it here (everything is is 72 dpi)

- iPhone 4S (2x): 960x640px
- iPhone 5/5S/5C (2x): 1136 x 640px
- iPhone 6: 1334 x 750px
- iPhone 6+: 2208 x 1242px -> downgrade to 1080 x
  1920px. You should do it in the biggest size

iPads

- iPad/2/Mini: 1024 x 768px
- iPad Air/Mini Retina: 2048 x 1536px

To put it as background I recommend it to put the content mode Aspect fill, and the iPhone 4S will get the 2x file, the same as iPhone 5/5S/5C and will scale a little so it will look perfectly

Comment: Works great thanks, i had it all right apart from i had set content mode to Aspect fit instead of Aspect fill.